# PDA to accept a language of strings containing more a's than b's

Tags: automata, formal-languages, pushdown-automaton

> Produce a PDA to recognise the following language : the language of strings containing more a's than b's

I have been struggling with this question for several days now, I seem to have hit a complete mental block. Would any one be able to provide some guidance or direction to how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem of "more a's than b's" can be solved by PDA.

All you have to do is:

- When input is `a` and the stack is either empty or has an `a` on the top, push `a` on the stack; pop `b`, if `b` is the top.
- When input is `b` and the stack is either empty or has an `b` on the top, push `b` on the stack; pop `a`, if `a` is on the top.
- Finally, when the string is finished, go to the final state with null input if `a` is on top of the stack. Otherwise you don't have more `a`'s than `b`'s.

Comment: Can it be done in a deterministic PDA, and in particular without using epsilon transition at the end (or at all)?

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with a more general solution to the problem concerning the number of as and bs, see the picture below:

[image: PDA for relations between as and bs]

where a > b means more as than bs and so does a < b , a = b.

Z means the bottom of stack, and A/B are stack symbols.

I'm excited about it because this PDA seperates the 3 different states. In your problem, you can just set the a > b state to be the final state and let a = b be the start state.

And if you want to step further, you can use this PDA to easily generate PDAs for a >= b, a - b >= 1, 2 <= a - b <= 3 etc, which is fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean strings of the form `a^nb^m`, where `n`>`m`.

The idea is relatively easy, for `a` you push it on the stack (in a loop), for `b` you switch to a separate loop to pop `a` from the stack. If the stack is ever empty, you give up with a FAIL. If in the first loop you get anything other than `a` or `b`, or in the second loop you get anything other than `b`, you give up with FAIL.

At the end you try to pop another `a` and if the stack is empty you give up with a FAIL (ie, you had at least as many `b`'s as `a`'s on the stack, possibly more). If not, SUCCESS.

Edit: As a side note, I'm not convinced this is the right site for this question, might be better on programmers. Not sure though so not voting to close.

Comment: Your suggestion works if you have more a's infront of the b's and if the string ends with an a. However it fails when the string ends with a 'b' or if the string has 'b' infront of 'a'

eg bbbaaaa would fail & baaaaab would also fail

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does, yes, but then that language is no longer a CFG now is it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, just one more question. What string variations will the PDA accept for this problem then, and what ones will it reject. I was under the assumption it could accept any variation of a's and b's as long as there were more a's in the string than b. Thanks

Comment: You tell me, it's your problem... For a CFG specifically though, to do the counting, you need a clear separation between the `a`'s and `b`'s (or if you get like `abbaa` you'll stack underflow on the 3rd character and you won't know if you have enough `a`'s coming up).

Answer (score 0):

PDA to accept more a's than b's

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Basic infromation of transaction is given in below figure.
[image]

Here is the complete transaction.

> **In it є is equal to NULL.**
>   $ sign is pushed into stack at the start of the string and pop at the end to determine the string has been completely read and end now. **qo is start state and q5 is final state**

It is Non-deterministic push down Automata (NPDA).So Due to NPDA the transaction of rejection string is not shown in it.
[image]

Comment: What happens if the first symbol in the string is `b`? This does not accept strings of the form `b^ia^j` where `i < j`. Am I missing something?

Comment: As per above comment, this doesn't handle the case if the input is b at first.